# Oracle procedure 'out' 'table of varchar2' type parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to get a list that is assigned  in one procedure(b) and return it as an OUT param to a variable of type 'table of varchar2' in procedure(a). How do I define the OUT param type?

ex.)

```
procedure_a()
type t_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10)

l_list t_list;

procedure_b(l_list);

end procedure_a;

procedure_b(out_list OUT ????)
```

what would the OUT type be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The type would need to be declared somewhere that both A and B could reference.  One option would be to declare the type in a package, i.e.

```
SQL> create package some_pkg
  2  as
  3    type t_list is table of varchar2(10);
  4
  5    procedure procedureA;
  6    procedure procedureB( p_list OUT t_list );
  7  end;
  8
  9  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body some_pkg
  2  as
  3    procedure procedureA
  4    as
  5      l_list t_list;
  6    begin
  7      procedureB( l_list );
  8      dbms_output.put_line( l_list.count );
  9    end;
 10
 11    procedure procedureB
 12      ( p_list OUT t_list )
 13    as
 14    begin
 15      select ename
 16        bulk collect into p_list
 17        from emp;
 18    end;
 19  end;
 20  /

Package body created.

SQL> exec some_pkg.procedureA;
16

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Another option would be to declare the type in SQL, i.e.

```
SQL> create type t_list
  2      as table of varchar2(10);
  3  /

Type created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace procedure procedureB( p_list OUT t_list )
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    select ename
  5      bulk collect into p_list
  6      from emp;
  7* end;
SQL> /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace procedure procedureA
  2  as
  3    l_list t_list;
  4  begin
  5    procedureB( l_list );
  6    dbms_output.put_line( l_list.count );
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec procedureA;
16

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. 

Just one last question, say I know the exact list (example static list of name), what would be the advantages of using TABLE OF TYPE VARCHAR2 vs. Vararray?

Comment: @help - If you know the number of elements a collection will contain and that number will never, ever change, there is no advantage to using a nested table rather than a VARRAY.  However, since the size of a nested table is not fixed, when the static list inevitably changes in the future, a nested table is more flexible.